# Merge concecutive pandas rows in a single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find a way to concatenate N rows of a df and produce a single row from them in a new df. The produced df should have distinct elements. Can we do it using build in functions?

```
Original df   Produced df N=2   Produced df N=3   
text_1        text_1 text_2     text_1 text_2 text_3 
text_2        text_3 text_4     text_4 text_5 text_6
text_3        text_5 text_6
text_4        
text_5
text_6
text_7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if there is built-in method, but you can generate a list of groupby values. Say you want 2 rows in a group, you can generate a list like `[1, 1, 2, 2]` etc.

Then groupby this list, join rows in each group:

```py
import itertools

n = 2

l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([([i]*n) for i in range(len(df['col'])//n)]))

df_ = df.iloc[:len(l)].groupby(l)['col'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x)).to_frame()
```

```
print(df_)

             col
0  text_1 text_2
1  text_3 text_4
2  text_5 text_6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `grouper` from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) can do, though we would need into account that it does pad with `None`s.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
def concat(x):
    return ' '.join(i for i in x if i is not None)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7']})
grouped = list(grouper(df['x'], n=3))
print(grouped)  # [('t1', 't2', 't3'), ('t4', 't5', 't6'), ('t7', None, None)]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y':[concat(i) for i in grouped]})
print(df2)
```

output:

```
          y
0  t1 t2 t3
1  t4 t5 t6
2        t7
```

Note: I used `list` in order to show what `grouper` produced, you might elect to use it directly i.e. `df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y':[concat(i) for i in grouper(df['x'], n=3)]})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use all Pandas/Numpy functions as follows:

Split the data column by [`np.array_split()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) and then create new dataframe by `pd.DataFrame()`.

```
n=3
data = np.array_split(df['col'].to_numpy(), np.ceil(df.shape[0] / n))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[' '.join(x) for x in data], columns=[f'Produced df N={n}'])
```

Output:

```
print(df2)


        Produced df N=3
0  text_1 text_2 text_3
1  text_4 text_5 text_6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.array_split(a[:len(a) // N * N], range(N, len(a) // N * N, N))
```

Input data:

```
a = np.array(["text_1", "text_2", "text_3", "text_4",
              "text_5", "text_6", "text_7"])
```

For `N = 2`:

```
[array(['text_1', 'text_2'], dtype='<U6'),
 array(['text_3', 'text_4'], dtype='<U6'),
 array(['text_5', 'text_6'], dtype='<U6')]
```

For `N = 3`:

```
[array(['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3'], dtype='<U6'),
 array(['text_4', 'text_5', 'text_6'], dtype='<U6')]
```

For `N = 4`:

```
[array(['text_1', 'text_2', 'text_3', 'text_4'], dtype='<U6')]
```